# Send APNS array of messages rather than sending individual messages

Tags: php, apple-push-notifications

```
foreach ($users AS $userToken) {
    $msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $userToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

    // Send it to the server
    $result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

    if (!$result)
        echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
    else
        echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;
}
```

For reference, `$fp` is a 'PHP Stream Context'. `$users` is an array of user tokens that have registered for push notifications.

Is there a better way of writing the above code so that fwrite can somehow send an array of messages to APNS rather than writing to the socket for each individual user?

Answer (score 0):

#### Notification payload

Push notifications are not intended to contain the actual payload (in your case the list of messages) but to notify the subscriber about new content. When receiving the notification the application retrieves the actual content from a web service.

From the docs:

> Important: Delivery of notifications is a “best effort”, not
>   guaranteed. It is not intended to deliver data to your app, only to
>   notify the user that there is new data available.
>
> *(Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html*)

Additionally, the size of the notification payload is limited to 256 bytes.

> The maximum size allowed for a notification payload is 256 bytes
>
> *(Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html)*

As a result you are supposed to provide a web service for your app to retrieve the actual list of messages. The notification payload only contains the number of new messages.

#### Communitcation with APNS

Your concept of sending individual requests for every user is correct, this is the way the APNS is designed. To increase the overall performance use multiple connections (using multiple threads) and ensure the underlying TCP connection is reused.

From the docs:

> You may establish multiple connections to the same gateway or to
>   multiple gateway instances. If you need to send a large number of push
>   notifications, spread them out over connections to several different
>   gateways. This improves performance compared to using a single
>   connection: it lets you send the push notifications faster, and it
>   lets APNs deliver them faster.
>
> *(Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH101-SW6)*

Keep in mind that it is your job to use the [Feedback Service](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH101-SW3) to remove unsubscribed device IDs from your internal list of subscribers. This also helps you in increasing the overall performance.

Comment: I'm not sure whether you've misunderstood or it's a poorly worded question, but there is only 1 message (a new news post body and title). When I want to post a news update I want to send it to all the users registered, are you saying that this architecture is wrong?

Comment: @jskidd3: Basically yes. Do not send the actual news to the users but a small teaser text (e.g the title of a news or "New content available"). Then use app installed on the client to pull the actual news from your web server and show it to the user.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what the app does. The ID of the post is also sent so that more information about the news can be fetched. My question is supposed to be asking if, is it right to send the payload 100 times with 100 different users to APNS, or should you only be sending 1 payload with an array of 100 different users? Does that make sense? If so, how can I do it? Currently I write that payload with each user to APNS, that seems a little inefficient, I should be sending 1 packet with all the users, no?